# Google Dataflow - PubSub to BigQuery - High Wall time, Performance Issue

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I tried to find an answer to my problem in google and stackoverflow, but even that there are some helpful posts, I could not find one that helped. I decided to give it a try here.

I wrote a small Dataflow Skript using the Apache Beam Python SDK. It does nothing special, just get data from PubSub and pushing it to BigQuery via the Streaming API.

The job runs. So far so good. But I found the performance somewhat below my expactations. In PubSub we have up to 30000 events per second, but even with 300 workers (600 vCPU) it only manages to process half of the events. My only indication that something is off, is the wall time of the last step (beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery) which sums up to "17 days 2 hr" even if the job runs only "22 min 27 sec" with 100 workers (200 vCPU).

My Pipeline looks like this:

```
        input_collection = (
            pipeline
            | 'R|Read PubSub Messages' >> ReadFromPubSub(topic=input_topic).with_output_types(bytes)
            | 'R|Convert to dict' >> beam.ParDo(SplitToDict())
    )

    run_collection = (
            input_collection
            | 'R|Prepare data' >> beam.ParDo(Data(label))
            | 'R|Write To BigQuery' >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(
               table_name,
               schema=schema,
               write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
               create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
               method='STREAMING_INSERTS',
               insert_retry_strategy="RETRY_ON_TRANSIENT_ERROR",
               batch_size=batch_size)
    )
```

My DoFn's look like this:

```
class SplitToDict(beam.DoFn):
def process(self, elements):
    elements_list = json.loads(elements)
    yield elements_list


class Data(beam.DoFn):
def __init__(self, label):
    self.label = label

def process(self, elements):
    if self.label == 1:
        yield {
            "nameId": elements["nameId"],
            "timestamp": elements["timestamp"]
        } ...
```

I set "streaming=True" and use "--enable_streaming_engine" as pipeline options. As I said, the pipeline runs, just not as fast and light as expected, considering the BigQuery Streaming API should be able to handle 100000 inserts per second.

Does anyone has even some small idea as to what is wrong or what I could try?

Regards
Michael

Comment: The pipeline looks all right to me. There will be some performance loss using python sdk for streaming in compared with java on dataflow since it involves more data serialization/deserialization but still the throughput you got seems very low. There are few things I can suggest base on my own experience:

- try out different batch sizes and see if it makes a difference or not

- see if the worker vm cpu usage is high to understand whether the resource was indeed the bottleneck
- check harness logs to see if there are suspicious error related to big query

Comment: Thank you for your input. The only message I found was this one: Missing required coder_id on grpc_port for -15692; using deprecated fallback. Any idea if this could be the culprit or how to resolve it.

Comment: I believe think this message is not related to the performance issue.

Comment: If you can it would be great if you could raise a support ticket. As they could have a deeper look. 
In the mean time a couple of other checks; In the monitoring UI can you expand the BigQueryIO and check where the time is spent. I dont have a python pipeine running to check at the moment, but there should be something like streaming write at the end. Also is the region you are running the Dataflow on the same as the BQ region? Another thing to look at would be the API & Services tab, have a look to see if any non 2xx code being returned...

Comment: I'm seeing a very similar situation with my pipeline. Did you ever manage to improve the performance @Recedit?

Comment: Honestly, no. I just deleted everything and had a look into the provided Java templates from Google. Then I took the PubsubToBigQuery template and changed IT according to my needs. But since I don't understand everything in the code, I'm planning in looking into Spotifies Scio API.